How does the size of $\{x: f(x) \text{ is locally constant}\}$ relate to the the size of $\text{im}(f)$?
I have been wondering (though I am not asking in this post) whether

a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is locally constant almost everywhere $\iff$ $\text{im}(f)$ is countable.

where by "locally constant at $x$" I mean that there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ so that $f$ is constant in $N$.
Because the discontinuitites of $f$ may be dense, I'm struggling to (dis)prove either direction, but I did get to ponder about the relation between the sets
$$D := \{x: f\text{ is locally constant at }x\} \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \text{im}(f).$$
Is the size of either $D$ or $\text{im}(f)$ bounded by the size of the other?

@AnneBauval I edited the post to (hopefully) clarify.

I don't think it is true in both directions, assuming the axiom of choice.

The Cantor function is locally constant on the the complement of the Cantor set, but surjects onto the interval $[0, 1]$.

And in the other direction from Jonathan's example, the indicator function of the rationals has finite image but is nowhere locally constant.

$D$ is open, hence $|D|=$ either $0$ or $|\Bbb R|$. Independently, $|{\rm im}(f)|$ may be any cardinality between $1$ and $|\Bbb R|$.

$|D|=0<2=im(f)$: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0& x\in\mathbb Q\\1& x\not\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$
$|D|=\mathfrak c=im(f)$: $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x& x<0 \\ 0 & x\in \mathbb Z^+\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$|D|=\mathfrak c>1=im(f)$: $$f(x)=0$$
